# how to search dd/mm in awk shell script in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to search as string in a file, the string is dd//mm. I need to count the number of occurrences of these string. How could I use the string in awk. At present I use something like this but result is empty:

```
awk ' /$1/$2/  {i++}END{print i}' filename.text
```

sample contents in file

```
09/Oct/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn
 09/OCt/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn
08/OCt/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: i need wc for this string 09/Oct ,the result will be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your awk is GNU:

```
$ awk '/'$1'\/'$2'/{i++}END{print i}' IGNORECASE=1 file
2
```

Comment: The IGNORECASE=1 was needed because your input file has 09/Oct and 09/OCt ,i.e, one with small c and one with capital C. If yours is not GNU, ignorecase will not work.

Comment: is it possible to check with this time like "09/Oct/2012:12", need a count of this string matches.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
awk '/dd\/\/mm/ { i++; } END { print i; }' filename.txt
```

Comment: @sona, then please post example contents of the file

Comment: 09/Oct/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn <br/>
09/OCt/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn <br/>
08/OCt/2012 filecontentesfilecontetn <br/>

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is counting, you can use `grep` for that.

```
$ grep -c '09/Oct' file.txt
```

The `-c` option tells it to count the number of times the pattern is matched.

But if you want tp use awk, you can pass the string in from a shell script, you can use an awk variable with `-v`:

```
#!/bin/sh

string="09/Oct"

awk -v string="$string" '$0 ~ string {i++} END {print i}' file
```

If you also need to match things in lower case (per the input shown in your question), you can convert everything to one case before comparison:

```
awk -v string="$string" 'BEGIN{string=tolower(string)} tolower($0) ~ string {i++} END {print i}' file
```

This should work with all versions of awk, not just the GNU variety (gawk).

Comment: It did for me.  Note that in your second line of example text, the letter "C" is upper case.  Did you want this match to be case insensitive?

Comment: Added a case insensitive version for you.